# Filesystem compatible with Mac OS X 10.7 and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, macos, partitioning, filesystems, ntfs

I have a laptop that installed with hackintosh (OSX 10.7) and Windows 7. I already created with 3 partitions with GUID partition table. Mac using Extended (Journaled), and windows 7 using NTFS.

The question is, if I want to create third partition, which can be read and also write by both OS,which filesystem should I use?

p.s.:
I heard about NTFS-3G for mac that can utilize NTFS volume, but it is paid software. I prefer change the partition filesystem rather than using the software.

Additional Information: My laptop is using HDD, and the last partition sized about 160GB.

Comment: There is a way to natively have OS X read/write NTFS. You can go with another file system, but then you run into file [size limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#Size_limits). I know this is a vague  comment with "there is a way" but you might need to google around for "enable native ntfs mac" and find a walkthrough that works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows7 supports the following on-disk formats:

- FAT16 (for floppy disks only)
- FAT32
- EFS (commonly called ExFAT)
- NTFS
- CDFS (for CD/DVDs only).

Your best bet is probably to go with FAT32 for partitions of less than 4GB or EFS/EXFAT for partitions above this limit.

Answer (score 2):

[FAT32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat32) and [exFAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exfat) will work between them.

> exFAT can be used where the NTFS file system is not a feasible solution, due to data structure overhead, or where the file size limit of the standard FAT32 file system (without FAT+ extension) is unacceptable.

Comment: "exFAT (Extended File Allocation Table) is a proprietary file system designed especially for flash drives"

is it okay to apply it on **HDD**?

Comment: For sure, HDD's aren't that choosy anyway.